# Why don't the array examples appear for my mocked Swagger 2 API on SwaggerHub?

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, swaggerhub

Here is the snippet of code:

```yaml
  /getappsettings:
    get:
      summary: Gets the collection of app settings.
      responses:
        200:
          description: The successful get app settings response.
          schema:
            type: array
            items:
              $ref: '#/definitions/KeyValueType'
            example:
              - key: 'APP_SUPPORT_EMAIL_ADDRESS'
                value: 'test@example.com'
              - key: 'APP_SUPPORT_PHONE_NUMBER'
                value: '08 9123 4567'
```

In the mocked API from SwaggerHub, it returns an empty array.

Comment: Contact SwaggerHub support.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I found was that it should be 'examples:' and up one level instead of 'example:' and also needed specify the content type - here is the working example below ...

Here is the snippet of code

```
  /getappsettings:
    get:
      summary: Gets the collection of app settings.
      responses:
        200:
          description: The successful get app settings response.
          schema:
            type: array
            items:
              $ref: '#/definitions/KeyValueType'
          examples:
            application/json:
              - key: 'APP_SUPPORT_EMAIL_ADDRESS'
                value: 'test@example.com'
              - key: 'APP_SUPPORT_PHONE_NUMBER'
                value: '08 9123 4567'
```

Comment: The spec in your question is also perfectly valid. This ^^ is just another way to write the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug in SwaggerHub's mock server, which is already fixed. Your definition now produces a mocked response containing the specified example array.